# Jquery disable mousedown event without losing the function associated to the event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I'm trying to disable a mousedown event for an element and then enable it without redifining the function related to the event.
When I do `$(this).off(mousedownEvent)` the event related is lost and I don't want to enable it with `$(this).on(mousedownEvent, function())`.
Is there a way to do so?

Comment: `I don't want to enable it with $(this).on(mousedownEvent, function())` why? It's pretty normal to do `$(this).off/on(mousedownEvent, yourFunctionSignature)`

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? are you disabling the mousedown event when you click on element? And then do you want some action at a later point when you click on the event again?

Answer (score 3):

Couldn't you just use an external function ?

```
function doStuffOnMouseDown(evt) {
    console.log('stuff happens here');
}

/* ENABLE */
$(this).on('mousedown', doStuffOnMouseDown);

/* DISABLE */
$(this).off('mousedown', doStuffOnMouseDown);

/* RE-ENABLE */
$(this).on('mousedown', doStuffOnMouseDown); // no suprise, it's just the same ?
```

That's pretty much the way to add and remove events without having to redefine the entire function body

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way it my opinion is to create the function then reference the function like this:

```
function myMouseEvent() {
    // Do some stuff
}
```

You then just pass the reference of the function to the method like this:

```
$(this).off('mousedown', myMouseEvent);
$(this).on('mousedown', myMouseEvent);
```